# Python Implicit Import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, implicit

I am looking to build a simple build system for fun in python. Inspired by gradle, my goal is to have several files store information about tasks (similar to build.gradle files). For example a single build file might look like:

```
from commands import *
tasks = {
    "Project1": {
        "dependencies": [
            "Project2"
        ],
        "commands": [
            ShellCommand("echo I am building Project1")
        ]
    },
    "Project2": {
        "commands": [
            ShellCommand("echo I am building Project2")
        ]
    }
}
```

I can dynamically load a bunch of similarly formed files via `importlib.import_module(module_name)` to create a master list of all tasks and do my processing based on that.

The difficult part I am running into is finding a clean way to support commands (e.g. `ShellCommand`) in these task files. I can write wrappers for all the commands, put them in a single `commands.py` file, and import that. However, the import statement is messy and shouldn't be required by task writers.

The obvious (and I am hoping naive) solution is to read each task file and prepend the import if it does not already exist. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

TL;DR: I want to replace the explicit `from commands import *` with an implicit import when I dynamically load the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typically not recommended, it might be ok for your use case, i.e. creating some kind of a domain specific language.

Just make your commands builtin-in variables before the module is imported:

```
__builtin__.ShellCommand = ShellCommand
__builtin__.ShellCommand2 = ShellCommand2
```

From now on, `ShellCommand` and `ShellCommand2` are available everywhere in your running program.

Comment: Yes, I think this should serve my needs. Thank you!